# twitter api with python name error in connection

Tags: python, api, twitter

```
from twitter import Twitter
t = Twitter(
    auth=OAuth(
         oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, 
         CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET
    )
)
pythonTweets = t.search.tweets(q = "#python")
print(pythonTweets)
```

it returns
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
      1 from twitter import Twitter
----> 2 t = Twitter(auth=OAuth('xxxxx','xxxxx',
      3 'xxxxx','xxxxx'))
      4 pythonTweets = t.search.tweets(q = "#python")
      5 print(pythonTweets)
```

NameError: name 'OAuth' is not defined

Comment: Please reformat your question so that it contains code in a correct format. also state your problem and explain yourself. [ask]

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to also import OAuth from the Twitter SDK.  Update the line to this:

`from twitter import Twitter, OAuth`

Comment: Could anyone upvoting comment with a link to any document/tutorial that doesn't have this?